# If $f(x)$ is continuous and $ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=1$, does this guarantee that the $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ diverges?

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Just as I described in the question, if $ f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\infty]$ and
$$ \displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=1$$
Then what about this integration?
$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty f(x) dx$$
For me, I'm a little bit suspicious that the integration is guaranteed to be divergent. My idea is from function $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ that is a continuous function. At the same time: $$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=0$$  and $$ \int_0 ^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \ dx =\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

This function is "oscillating" up and down on the x-axis in a suitable way resulting in it being convergent.

Then, I think that maybe there can also exist a function, but it is oscillating on $ y=1$ in a very suitable way which makes it convergent

---

Failed example, plz ignore this:

Then I think by constructing a piece wise continuous function:

$$\begin{cases} 
f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x} +1 & \forall x\in[2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi] \\ \\ 
f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x} -1 & \forall x\in[(2k+1)\pi,(2k+2)\pi] 
\end{cases}$$ for $k=0,1,2...$

---

But I'm not certain whether my idea is right and can't really come up with any counterexamples.

Also if the integration is indeed guaranteed to be divergent, I don't know how to prove it.

Any helps? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show that there is an $x_0>0$ such that $f(x)>\frac{1}{2}$ if $x>x_0$? What does that tell you about $\int_{x_0 }^\infty  {f(x)dx}$?

Comment: Yeah, that can make sure that $\int_{x_0}^\infty f $ is convergent right?

Comment: Are you sure about that? $\int_{x_0 }^\infty  {f(x)dx}  > \int_{x_0 }^\infty  {\frac{1}{2}dx}  = ?$

Comment: My bad, I think in a wrong way

Comment: Improper integral exists if and only if they are bounded in the region of improperness. In your particular case, that means $\int_0^\infty f$ exists if and only if $\int_M^\infty f$ exists for all $M$ (and in fact, this goes to zero as $M \to \infty$). By definition of the limit, $f > 1/2$ eventually and then the integrals $\int_M^\infty f = \infty$ identically.

Comment: The necessary condition for convergence of an integral $\int_{0}^\infty f(x) dx$ was $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) =0$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @DogeChan That is actually a common misconception. If $\int_0^\infty f$ exists, $\lim\limits_{x \to\infty} f(x)$ need not exist, not even when $f$ is continuous. However, if both $\int_0^\infty f$ and $\lim\limits_\infty f$ exist, then the limit is zero.

Comment: @Yink Your question does not make much sense now. Your example does not have the property $f(x)\to 1$. What do you want to ask?

Comment: @Willian M. why $f(x)$ > 1/2 will cause the integration converges? Could you please explain this?

Comment: @Yink It will cause it to diverge. If $f\to 1$ then there is an $x_0>0$ such that $f(x)>\frac{1}{2}$ if $x>x_0$. Thus, $$
\int_{x_0 }^\infty  {f(x)dx}  > \int_{x_0 }^\infty  {\frac{1}{2}dx}  = \frac{1}{2}\int_{x_0 }^\infty  {dx}  = \frac{1}{2}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{X \to  + \infty } \int_{x_0 }^X {dx}  = \frac{1}{2}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{X \to  + \infty } X =  + \infty 
$$

Comment: Why in particular 1/2? It seems that 1/3, 1/4 also works....

Comment: @Yink yes, any $1-\delta > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ will do the trick.

Comment: @Yink It does not matter, the conclusion is the same. I showed the divergence, that is what matters. You can pick your favourite number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Also, where does the continuous property works? Is this also true if the function isn't continuous?

Comment: @WilliamM: $\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x=2$ converges, yet $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ is not bounded near $0$.

Comment: @robjohn I meant the integral, not the function.

Comment: @Yink I belive continuity is given to have a sufficient condition for integrability, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity is not required. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=1$, there is some $x_0>0$ such that for all $x>x_0$ we have $f(x)>\frac{1}{2}$. In order for $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ to converge $\int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ must converge.

$\int_{x_0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \, dx$ clearly diverges, as $\int_{x_0}^{x} \frac{1}{2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)\overset{x\to\infty}{\to}\infty$. By the comparison test $\int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ diverges as well, so that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ necessarily diverges.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, even if $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is defined in improper sense.
Let $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$. Suppose the contrary that $I=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)$
exists. For $\varepsilon=1$, there exists $x_{1}>0$ such that $|F(x)-I|<\varepsilon$
whenever $x\geq x_{1}$. Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=1>\frac{1}{2}$,
there exists $x_{2}>0$ such that $f(x)>\frac{1}{2}$ whenever $x\geq x_{2}$.
Take $x_{3}=\max(x_{1},x_{2})+1$, $x_{4}=x_{3}+100$. On one hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
|F(x_{4})-F(x_{3})| & \leq & \left|F(x_{3})-I\right|+\left|F(x_{4})-I\right|\\
 & < & 2\varepsilon\\
 & = & 2.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & |F(x_{4})-F(x_{3})|\\
 & = & \left|\int_{x_{3}}^{x_{4}}f(t)dt\right|\\
 & \geq & \int_{x_{3}}^{x_{4}}\frac{1}{2}dt\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2}(x_{4}-x_{3})\\
 & = & 50.
\end{eqnarray*}
We obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Divergence is definitely guaranteed. Consider this: suppose that $f$ has an antiderivative $F.$ Then by L'Hopital's theorem, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x).$$ By the fundamental theorem of calculus, since $f$ is continuous, you are guaranteed that $$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ for some $a.$ Therefore, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}{x}=1.$$ However, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x=\infty,$$ so it necessarily is the case that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_a^{\infty}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\infty$$ as well. Why? Because if the integral were finite, then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}{x}=0.$$